# Prevent PC from falling asleep when a certain program is running?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, powercfg

I have a phone mirroring program (`scrcpy`) and set my laptop to fall asleep after 10 minutes. I use it mainly to watch live TV, but the laptop will turn off while it's running. After reading around on the web, I tried using `powercfg -requestsoverride` for that program, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I supposed to do?

**EDIT:** I'm using windows 10 BTW.

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 3):

**KeepDisplayOn** - Runs a program preventing sleeping or the display turning off while the program runs

*This uses the inbuilt compilers in Windows 10 (and have been since Windows Vista) - there are three VB.NET compilers and three C# compilers - just copy each text file into the same folder and double click the batch file to make the program.*

This uses API call *SetThreadExecutionState* (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) which is how programs tell windows not to sleep.

Runs a program preventing sleeping or the display turning off while the program runs

**To Use**

```
 KeepDisplayOn "C:\windows\notepad"
 KeepSystemOn "C:\windows\notepad"
```

---

```
@Echo Off
ECHO Three files follow
ECHO PreventSleep.bat
ECHO.
ECHO This file compiles KeepDisplayOn.vb and KeepSystemOn.vb to KeepDisplayOn.exe and KeepSystemOn.exe using the system VB.NET compiler.
ECHO.
ECHO Runs a program preventing sleeping or the display turning off while the program runs
ECHO.
ECHO To Use
ECHO      KeepDisplayOn "C:\windows\notepad"
ECHO      KeepSystemOn "C:\windows\notepad"
ECHO.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\KeepDisplayOn.vb" /out:"%~dp0\KeepDisplayOn.exe" /target:winexe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\KeepSystemOn.vb" /out:"%~dp0\KeepSystemOn.exe" /target:winexe
pause
```

---

```
'KeepSystemOn.vb
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Module MyApplication 
Public Declare UNICODE Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal esFlags as Integer) as Integer
Public Const  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &h40
Public Const  ES_CONTINUOUS = &h80000000
Public Const  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &h2
Public Const  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &h1
Public Const  ES_USER_PRESENT = &h4

 Public Sub Main ()
  Dim wshshell as Object
  Dim Ret as Integer
  WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_System_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)
  WshShell.Run(Command(), , True)
 End Sub
End Module
```

---

```
'KeepDisplayOn.vb
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Module MyApplication 
Public Declare UNICODE Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal esFlags as Integer) as Integer
Public Const  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &h40
Public Const  ES_CONTINUOUS = &h80000000
Public Const  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &h2
Public Const  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &h1
Public Const  ES_USER_PRESENT = &h4

 Public Sub Main ()
  Dim wshshell as Object
  Dim Ret as Integer
  WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_Display_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)
  WshShell.Run(Command(), , True)
 End Sub
End Module
```

From https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/keepdisplayon-runs-program-preventing.html

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how I'm supposed to do this

Comment: Copy the three text files above into the same folder. The names to use are on the first line of the two vb files. Double click the batch file and you'll make two executables.  Then `C:\somefolder\KeepDisplayOn "C:\windows\notepad"` in a shortcut, or Start - Run dialog. While notepad runs the display will stay on.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `SetThreadExecutionState` to both `ES_Display_Required` and `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` instead of making 2 script/exe file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for compilation of vbs scripts, this can be done by a Powershell script, which I just published on [GitHub](https://github.com/Simbiat/SnoozeGuard) (and below).
This script allows you to pass lists of processes, that you want to monitor to keep either your system (`-requiresSystem`) or both the system and display (`-requiresDisplay`) from sleeping. Display sleeping can be prevented, if a process from respective list is in focus or generally not minimized/hidden (depends on `-focusOnly` parameter). It can be run once or indefinitely (`-oneTime`) with a customizable polling rate (`-pollingRate`).
Example of usage:

```
SnoozeGuard.ps1 -requiresDisplay "mstsc" -requiresSystem "handbrake" -focusOnly 0 -pollingRate 120 -oneTime 0
```

Code itself

```
param (
    [string[]]$requiresSystem,
    [string[]]$requiresDisplay,
    [int]$pollingRate = 120,
    [bool]$focusOnly = $true,
    [bool]$oneTime = $false
)

# Check if PowerState type is already defined (GPT suggests this, not sure why, since for me it does need to do this: possible for compatibility reasons?)
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'PowerState').Type) {
    # Define the PowerState enumeration
    Add-Type @"
        using System;

        [Flags]
        public enum PowerState : uint
        {
            ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001,
            ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002
        }
"@
}

# Check if NativeMethods type is already defined
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'NativeMethods').Type) {
    # Define the NativeMethods class
    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        public class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
        }
"@
}

if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'WindowMethods').Type) {
    # DEfine WindowMethods class
    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        public class WindowMethods {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
        }
"@
}

function SetExecutionState {
    param (
        [PowerState]$esFlags
    )

    $state = [PowerState]::ES_CONTINUOUS -bor $esFlags
    
    # Suppress the output of SetThreadExecutionState
    $result = [NativeMethods]::SetThreadExecutionState($state)

    if ($result -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Error: Unable to set execution state." -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    Get-StateNames -Value ([NativeMethods]::SetThreadExecutionState(0))  # Get the current state
}

function Get-StateNames {
    param (
        [uint32]$Value
    )

    if ($Value -band [PowerState]::ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED -and $Value -band [PowerState]::ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED) {
        Write-Host "Fully awake" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
    }
    elseif ($Value -band [PowerState]::ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED) {
    Write-Host "System is awake" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
    }
    elseif ($Value -band [PowerState]::ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED) {
    Write-Host "Display is awake" -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Feeling sleepy" -ForegroundColor Gray
    }
}

function IsProcessRunning {
    param (
        [string[]]$processName
    )

    foreach ($name in $processName) {
        Write-Host "Searching for ""$name""..." -ForegroundColor Gray
        $process = Get-Process -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($process) {
            Write-Host "Process ""$name"" found" -ForegroundColor Gray
            return $true
        }
    }

    return $false
}

function IsProcessFocused {
    param (
        [string]$name
    )

    $foregroundWindow = [NativeMethods]::GetForegroundWindow()

    if ($foregroundWindow -eq [IntPtr]::Zero) {
        return $false
    }

    $processId = 0
    [NativeMethods]::GetWindowThreadProcessId($foregroundWindow, [ref]$processId) | Out-Null

    $focusedProcess = Get-Process -Id $processId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($focusedProcess -and $focusedProcess.ProcessName -eq $name) {
        return $true
    }

    return $false
}

function IsProcessVisible {
    param (
        [string]$processName
    )

    # Get the process by name
    $process = Get-Process -Name $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Check if the process is found
    if ($process -ne $null) {
        # Check if the main window is minimized or hidden
        if ($process.MainWindowHandle -ne [IntPtr]::Zero) {
            $mainWindow = $process.MainWindowHandle
            $isMinimized = [WindowMethods]::IsIconic($mainWindow)
            $isVisible = [WindowMethods]::IsWindowVisible($mainWindow)

            if ($isMinimized -or -not $isVisible) {
                return $false
            } else {
               return $true
            }
        }
    }
    return $false
}

while (($requiresSystem -ne $null -and $requiresSystem.Length -gt 0) -or ($requiresDisplay -ne $null -and $requiresDisplay.Length -gt 0)) {
    if (IsProcessRunning $requiresDisplay) {
        $executionState = [PowerState]::ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED

        foreach ($name in $requiresDisplay) {
            if (($focusOnly -and (IsProcessFocused $name)) -or (-not $focusOnly -and ((IsProcessFocused $name) -or (IsProcessVisible $name)))) {

                Write-Host "Process ""$name"" wants display" -ForegroundColor Gray
                $executionState = $executionState -bor [PowerState]::ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED
                break  # Exit the loop once one focused process is found
            }
        }

        SetExecutionState -esFlags $executionState
    } elseif (IsProcessRunning $requiresSystem) {
        SetExecutionState -esFlags ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED
    } else {
        Write-Host "No processes found" -ForegroundColor Gray
    }

    if ($oneTime) {
        break
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $pollingRate
    }
}

# Release the execution state when the process is not running
SetExecutionState -esFlags ES_CONTINUOUS | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

[Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/) has a feature to keep the PC from sleeping when specified processes are running. It calls this a *Prevent Sleep* rule, and it can be applied to the display only, or entire PC. Internally, it uses the [SetThreadExecutionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) API, called by its 'Governor' service.

[image: Process Lasso context menu offering Prevent Sleep (Keep Awake) rule]